# C++ vector и поиск

Tags: массивы, vector, оптимизация, c++

Начал потихоньку пилить не большую консольную программу... Есть массив vector<string> в нем хранятся ip адреса, около 2-3т адресов, раз в 30 секунд, проводится парсинг файла, на предмет новых ip адресов, решил попользоваться binary_search(ips.begin(), ips.end(), str), но он не всегда находит уже существующие адреса и приходится применять стандартный перебор. Какой способ быстрее и стоит ли применять оба, то есть, если бинарный сказал что не нашел, то проверять обычным перебором, прирост IP адресов не большой 20-30 каждую минуту?

Comment: Вопрос не по теме: а зачем хранить это все в памяти???

Comment: Эти ip адреса хранятся лишь одну сессию список обновляется постоянно и смысла хранить данные в БД нет смысла.

Comment: а почему бы не использовать std::set?

Comment: @avengerweb, binary search работает с рассортированным массивом. Может Вы просто добавляете в конец, а потом не сортируете? Поэтому и не находит.

В *правильно* организованных данных описанная Вами ситуация не должна возникать.

Кстати, обратите внимание на комментарий @gecube (т.е. воспользуйтесь хэш-таблицей).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вообще, хранить основную массу данных в отсортированном виде, а небольшую часть - в "отстойнике" - хорошая идея. И иногда, естественно, сортировать отстойник и сливать с сортированными данными. Вы же не ищите binary_search'ем по не полностью отсортированному массиву?

Но в данном случае, std::set придуман ровно для этого. Так что, если устраивает, - нечего заморачиваться с чем-то другим.

А ещё очень желательно IP'шники перевести в int'ы. Я думаю, разница в скорости Вас удивит.

Comment: Это так скажем моя первая подобная программа(на c++, я php программист...) про set я в принципе и не знал, но он в самый раз подходит, по поводу перевода в int, может имеется какая либо функция для перевода?

Comment: Конечно, см. `man inet_addr`